# Библиотека EGA на си для микроконтроллеров

Tags: c

Вопрос.
Какую можно использовать библиотеку для МК для вывода сообщений в режиме EGA ?

Comment: Попробуйте svgalib возможно ваш чип поддерживается.

Comment: Очень обширный вопрос. Уточняйте входные данные платформы. См. мой комментарий к своему предыдущему вопросу.